# select2: load asynchronous data through promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2, promise

What is the best place to load the options for select2 asynchronously. I want the same facility as `ajax`, but instead of select2 sending an ajax request, it needs to load the values asynchronously from a promise object. Below code works, in which I load the data in `query`, but which means every keystroke, invocation of select dropdown, it will query the data. so, what is the correct configuration?

### code:

```
var items2 = [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Name": "First"
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "Name": "Second"
            },
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "Name": "Third"
            }
        ];

        var names = function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.resolve(items2);
            }, 200);

            return deferred.promise;
        };


        var query: function (query) {
                var results = [];

                names().then(function(d){
                    $.each(d, function(index, item){
                        results.push({
                            id: item.Id,
                            text: item.Name
                        });
                    });

                    query.callback({  results: results });
                })
        };
```

### Edit

looking at the [source](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js#L3204), it looks like it only allows either `ajax` or `local` for querying data. It would have been ideal if `local` takes a function which returns the data. Am I on the right track? is there an easy way to patch it?

thanks

```
// exports
    window.Select2 = {
        query: {
            ajax: ajax,
            local: local,
            tags: tags
        }, util: {
            debounce: debounce,
            markMatch: markMatch,
            escapeMarkup: defaultEscapeMarkup,
            stripDiacritics: stripDiacritics
        }, "class": {
            "abstract": AbstractSelect2,
            "single": SingleSelect2,
            "multi": MultiSelect2
        }
    };
```

### Edit2:

'local` indeed accepts a function. but it doesn't play nicely with remote data, as the data is received with a delay (async), drop down is not populated with the new data. I have to close and open the drop-down again. This is not intuitive for the user.

Answer (score 0):

As far I see, select2 invokes an `ajax` call for each key stroke, and opening the select box. I can get the same behavior using `query` (with promise) as in the original question. I was expecting select2 loads the data once, then do rest locally (search, and further invocation till any data change). looks like this is not an option. I may just cache my results locally. Better answer welcome.

Comment: how to get it with query (promise)?